# Probability of getting two balls of different colours.

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

> **Question:** An urn contain 9 balls three red four blue and two are green. Three balls are drawn at random without replacement from the urn. What is the probability that all three balls different colour.

**Solution**

The way of solving it which I saw on youtube was :
$$\tag{1} {3 \choose 1} \times {4 \choose 1} \times {2 \choose 1}/{9 \choose 3},$$

which gives the answer $2/7$.

How I like to think about this is, since it is without replacement so $$\tag{2}(\text{prob. of red balls}) (\text{prob. of blue balls}) (\text{prob. of green ball}) = \frac 39 \frac 48 \frac 27 \times 6 ;$$

multiplying with six as there can be 6 possible arrangements of three different balls.

**Where I am stuck** :
I am unable to picture what's happening in 1st formula.

If I see it like probability = (favorable outcom)/(total outcomes)

*So does ${ 9\choose 3}$ telling me the sample space?*

If yes, how? ${9 \choose 3}$ is selection it does care about order, like 'abc' and 'bca' are same for combination, so how can it be sample space.

If I am using any wrong logic please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! On this forum, you are required to first show what efforts you have made, and where you are stuck. Please edit in your work.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 1):

The important point to note is that the count for the numerator and denominator must be done in a consistent manner.

You may best understand it by *combinations* vs *permutations*

When you are using the formula $\large\frac{\binom31\binom21\binom41}{\binom93}$,
you have used *combinations* in both numerator and denominator, so there is consistency.

But when you simply write $\large \frac39\frac48\frac27$, the numerator is essentially a *combination* $\binom31\binom41\binom21$, while the denominator is a *permutation* $9\cdot8\cdot7 = ^9P_3$
so we multiply the numerator by $3!$ to also make the numerator a *permutation*

Comment: Sir, could you please help me have some more clarity over the formula that why in formula we are not bothering about order. A simple example and explanation might help me strengthen my basics.

Comment: @PrathamSinha: I have simplified the presentation to explain it in terms of *combinations* vs *permutations*

Comment: @PrathamSinha A case can be made that this is an unfair posting for you to try to attack.  Apparently, you have never studied Combinatorics.  This explains why the answer of true blue anil is unclear to you.  I suggest that you find the right book on Combinatorics, one that has many, many exercises for you to solve, open the book to page 1, and attack.

Comment: For me to try to attack??   Ok, I guess, erroneously I have violated some of the rules and regulations of this websites.    And this is not a homework problem.    Yes I am still learning permutations and combinations, I just wanted to clear my doubt, I will practice questions. But sir I would still need a place to clear my doubts. Could you suggest me some places like MSE.

Comment: @PrathamSinha Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.